# Facebook Like Box - photos appearing stretched

Tags: photo, facebook-apps, facebook-likebox, distortion

I've just added the Facebook like box to www.glasgow.ac.uk/careers.

It seems to be working fine, except that photos are appearing stretched/distorted in the box (i.e. one at the moment is about twice the height it should be.)

We've changed from the default box width, but even at the default this was happening with our pictures. Is there any way to fix this?

Many thanks,

Jamie

Comment: Confirmed bug: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/173741066089584/

Answer (score 1):

Jamie:

Based on multiple examples, I have inferred the algorithm that Facebook are using to resize photos in the Like Box. It's unusual and it's not one that I would choose. I suspect that when they get a handle on what they're actually doing, they will change it.

But right now, as per my calculations, the only large photo size that will shrink without squeezing, is 170 x 320.

David

Answer (score 1):

It should also be noted that the CSS that Facebook uses in the iframe has a max width of 120px set.