# How to resize facebook stream images with jquery or js

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

On the facebook like box , i want to resize the post images shown in the feed , but i can't get it to work.I tried with jquery , something like `('.6ks_ img').width(295);` but it just won't work.

The problem lies on the images inside the like box ( the images from the posts shown on like-box) and not in the box-itself.

Here's a link that explains it : link. If you look at the sidebar below the twitter widget, there are two facebook boxes. The first one is from the theme and the second one taken from facebook. My question is why wont the images scale on the first one, but they do on the later. (the theme creator couldn't help me )

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> 

<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="facebook.com/esportsmansion"; data-width="360" data-height="655" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="true" data-show-border="true">
```

Comment: You should atleast do some research work, try to write code and post that too..

Comment: You could of added the code containing your `like box` but I don't think it is worth down voting. Some people just enjoy making it hard for people to get answers. So if you dont want to keep getting down voted just add some more code. Let me know if my answer helped you bud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what your fix is, 
You downloaded the `github styling` from the link provided in this answer. Also you seem to have to adjust the size of the `fb box` till your pictures look appropriate.

This is pertaining to sizing the `img` inside of the `Facebook Like Box`.
A confirmed bug `img` stretching and looking distorted

[Click Here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/173741066089584/)

I found that on `Stackoverflow` 
[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689824/facebook-like-box-photos-appearing-stretched)

"It should also be noted that the CSS that Facebook uses in the iframe has a max width of 120px set."

This is pertaining to sizing the `Facebook Like Box`
I found a link to a github repo that seems to be a `responsive css solution`

[Click Here](https://gist.github.com/smeranda/2571173)

If for what ever reason that solution does not work,
I suspect you can wrap it in a div and do it with `css`

```
#fbcss {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

    <div id="fbcss">
    facebook like box here
    </div>
```

Comment: I suppose i wasn't very clear, and i am sorry about the lack of code, but i don't think the code I created would have helped. The problem lies on the images inside the like box ( the images from the posts shown on like-box) and not in the box-itself.

Comment: Here's a link that explains it : [link](http://www.dermanisae.gr/oursite/). If you look at the sidebar below the twitter widget, there are two facebook boxes. The first one is from the theme and the second one taken from facebook. My question is why wont the images scale on the first one, but they do on the later. (the theme creator couldn't help me )

Comment: And this is the code i got from facebook (had to go to work to see it soz for multiple comments)  <div id="fb-root"></div>
 
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/esportsmansion" data-width="360" data-height="655" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="true" data-show-border="true"></div>

Comment: So it appears you must keep the img under the 120px max. If you would like more help I strongly suggest showing a screen shot.

Comment: And from reading at some of those resources it sounds like resizing the `like box` will resize the `img`.

Comment: NDiaz , thanks for all your effort mate. I ll be uploading a screenshot in 2 hours or so (when i get off work). But if you want, you can visit the link above and check it live. The two boxes are exactly the same size, but the images aren't scaling the same.

Comment: Resizing an image kinda made it better,but still not what I was looking for. (one thing i noticed is that ,unlike the bigger images,the 120px wide image shows up the same in the 2 boxes).

Comment: @pavlos No problem. I hope I can help you find the answer. The link you have provided seems to be broken.

Comment: Hey there Diaz, i had tried the solution you told me you found here with the responsive layout, but i still had problems. But for some reason, (siderbar width i suppose) when i got the facebook-like-box down to 345px wide from 360 or 380px made it happen. Thanks for all the help mate

Comment: I am sorry I did not understand what fixed it exactly? Please tell me and I will add it exactly the way it is to my answer so if someone else has this problem they will easily be able to find the answer. :)

Comment: So,i used the solution found in the github link you provided (once again, sorry for not being clear enough). To be exact i used the styling user eomonteiro had in a comment. That made the container of the like box to stretch so it gets 100% the width of the sidebar. After that i resized the facebookbox to 345px wide (still stretching to 100% of the sidebar though) and did the trick. (345 was by trial and error till i get the correct width).If you need any more info (sidebar width or smthing) so you can get it all in a "global" answer , feel free to ask. Thanks again mate.

Comment: If i get this correctly, someone must get the right width of the box for the images being used (mine were 350px wide).Then make it responsive with githubs styling and finaly place it in another container having the dimensions needed.

Comment: Awesome I updated my answer. I am glad I could help. Please accept my answer if your question is answered.

Comment: Done, and hmmmmm thanks again. Just for your information though, the images came to the right width, but not height. (which i have no problem with).And i dont think there is a workaround for height styling.